# control multiple keyframe animations of single element via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a text and I want to apply two different keyframe animations named `animeUp` and `animeDown` to it. Also, I want to be able to control the animation using javascript.

The desired result is a javascript line of code to initiate `animeUp` animation and another one to initiate the `animeDown`...

I've tried to play and pause the animations by adding CSS classes that change the `animation-play-state` but using this approach I can only control one of the animations!

**Note: we want the keyframe animations as they are...**

```js
//pause the animation at first
document.getElementById("Text").classList.add("paused");

//after 2 seconds initiate the animation
setTimeout(function(){  
document.getElementById("Text").classList.add("played");
}, 2000)
```

```css
html{
    overflow:hidden;
}

#Text{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;  
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 7.5vw;
    color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    left: 1vw;
    top: -45vh;
    animation: animeUp 0.5s ease-out ;
    animation: animeDown 0.5s ease-in ;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animeUp {
   from { top: 10vh }
   to   { top: -50vh }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animeDown {
   from { top: -50vh }
   to   { top:  10vh }
}

.paused {
   -webkit-animation-play-state: paused !important; 
}

.played {
   -webkit-animation-play-state: running !important; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div class = "container">
 <p id="Text">Tutorial</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class for each animation and toggle between the two.

I threw together a demo, nothing too fancy just to get the idea across.

```js
document.querySelector('.up').onclick = (e) => {
  document.getElementById("Text").classList.add("animeup");
  document.getElementById("Text").classList.remove("animedown");
  e.target.disabled = "true";
  document.querySelector('.down').removeAttribute("disabled");
}

document.querySelector('.down').onclick = (e) => {
  document.getElementById("Text").classList.remove("animeup");
  document.getElementById("Text").classList.add("animedown");
  document.querySelector('.up').removeAttribute("disabled");
  e.target.disabled = "true";
}
```

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#Text {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 7.5vw;
  color: red;
  left: 1vw;
  top: -50vh;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animeUp {
  from {
    top: 10vh
  }
  to {
    top: -50vh
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animeDown {
  from {
    top: -50vh
  }
  to {
    top: 10vh
  }
}

.animeup {
  animation: animeUp 0.5s ease-out;
}

.animedown {
  animation: animeDown 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<button class="up" disabled>Up</button>
<button class="down">Down</button>

<div class="container">
  <p id="Text">Tutorial</p>
</div>
```